# How to associate unique id with text in word counting with spark

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have an RDD that is populated as

```
id              txt 
1              A B C
2              A B C
1              A B C
```

The result of my word count (pyspark) should be for a combination of string and id associated with it. Example:

```
[(u'1_A',2), (u'1_B',2), (u'1_C',2),(u'2_A',1),(u'2_B',1),(u'2_C',1)]
```

I tried using a user defined function to combine id with string splits from text. It, however, complains that the append function is unavailable in this context.

Appreciate any code samples that will set me in the right direction.

Comment: your source RDD is a tuple of 2 columns id and txt? something like this `[(1,'A B C'), (2, 'A B C'), (1,'A B C')]`?

Answer (score 0):

the below snippet should work

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([(1,'A B C'), (2, 'A B C'), (1,'A B C')])
result = rdd \
          .map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1].split(' '))) \
          .flatMap(lambda x: [ '%s_%s'% (x[0],y) for y in x[1] ]) \
          .map(lambda x: (x,1)) \
          .reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x + y) 
result.collect()
```

**Output**

```
[('1_C', 2), ('1_B', 2), ('1_A', 2), ('2_A', 1), ('2_B', 1), ('2_C', 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution using PySpark Dataframe. Mainly, the code uses `explode` and `split` to split the `txt` column. Then, use `groupby` and `count` to count number of pairs.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([(1,'A B C'), (2, 'A B C'), (1,'A B C')])
df = rdd.toDF(['id', 'txt'])

df_agg = df.select('id', func.explode(func.split('txt', ' '))).\
    groupby(['id', 'col']).\
    count().\
    sort(['id', 'col'], ascending=True)

df_agg.rdd.map(lambda x:(str(x['id']) + '_' + x['col'], x['count'] )).collect()
```

**Output**

```
[('1_A', 2), ('1_B', 2), ('1_C', 2), ('2_A', 1), ('2_B', 1), ('2_C', 1)]
```